# Geo-fencing with Bing SDS

Tags: javascript, azure, geocoding, bing-maps, geofencing

Does anyone know how to create geofences with Bing Spatial Data services?

I am trying to follow along with this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/04/03/geo-fencing-with-bing-spatial-data-services-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx) but the documentation doesn't really help for steps on how to set up the geofences in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to insert and set the geofences, you will have to create your own datasource using the Data Source Management capabilities of the Bing Maps Spatial Data Service.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585132.aspx

**Do it by code:**

A sample uri that will add the remote content (stored on Azure) will look like this:

```
http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Dataflows/LoadDataSource?loadOperation=complete&dataLocation=http://myAzureAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myEntityData&input=xml&o=xml&key=masterKey&queryKey=queryKey
```

**Do it with the Bing Maps Account center:**

> To upload the file that contains your data schema and entity data,
>   follow these steps. Sign in to the Bing Maps Account Center with your
>   Bing Maps Account. If you do not have a Bing Maps Account, see
>   Creating a Bing Maps Account.
>
> In the Bing Maps Account Center, select the Upload data to a data
>   source under Data Sources.
>
> Provide the following information
>
> Data source name: The name of the data source where you want to
>   publish the data. If a data source with this name does not exist, it
>   will be created when you publish the data. For data source name
>   requirements, see the preceding Data Source Name Requirements section.
>
> Master key: Select the Bing Maps Key to use for the data source.
>
> If you are creating a new data source, select the Bing Maps Key that
>   you want to use to manage the data source.
>
> If you are updating a data source with new data, you must use the
>   master key that you specified when you created the data source. To
>   view a list of master and query keys for data sources, click the View
>   data source information link under Data Sources on the Bing Maps
>   Account Center.
>
> Query key [new data sources only]: If you are creating a new data
>   source, you can select a Bing Maps Key to use to query the data
>   source. The query key must be a different Bing Maps Key than the
>   master key.
>
> Data file type: Select the type of input file you want to upload.
>
> Data file : Browse to the file that contains the data (schema and
>   entity data) that you want to publish. You can format your data by
>   using XML, CSV (comma-separated value), TAB (tab-delimited) or PIPE
>   (pipe-delimited) formats. The file extensions expected for each file
>   type are:
>
> .xml :XML
>
> .csv :comma-separated value
>
> .txt :pipe-delimited
>
> .txt :tab-delimited
>
> Publish without geocoding: Select this option if you want to upload
>   and publish your data to a data source in one step without geocoding
>   the entity location data.
>
> Set data source access to public or private: When you choose to
>   publish without geocoding, you have the option to make the data source
>   public or private. A public data source can be queried by anyone with
>   a Bing Maps Key and the query URL. If you are updating an existing
>   URL, make sure you choose the correct access setting because it
>   overrides the existing setting.
>
> After a data source is published, you can change the data source
>   access at any time from the Manage my data sources page.
>
> Click Submit to start the upload.

More information about the possibilities regarding uploading and publishing of your own datasources can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650600

Comment: I have created a data source successfully but how do I define a geofence area? Can this be done in the Entity data? For instance I want to create a geofence around a school, at the moment my data source only has a singular point, can I add others in the data schema to create a square fence?